# Sorting by price, A-Z React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to filter the product list below by price and alphabetically. I know I have to create two states but I don't know how to approach the code afterwards.

```
<Col lg="6" md="6" sm="6" xs="12" className="mb-5">
              <div className="sorting__widget text-end">
                <select className="w-50">
                  <option>Default</option>
                  <option value="ascending">Alphabetically, A-Z</option>
                  <option value="descending">Alphabetically, Z-A</option>
                  <option value="high-price">High Price</option>
                  <option value="low-price">Low Price</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </Col>

            {displayPage.map((item) => (
              <Col lg="3" md="4" sm="6" xs="6" key={item.id} className="mb-4">
                <ProductCard item={item} />
              </Col>
            ))}
```

Comment: the best practice is to do it in the backend , send it throw the ai and you can order there.

Comment: you can sort lists in js. have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

Like it has been said, it is a better practice to do it in the backend but assuming you have fix data and you want to do it on the front you could make a function like this on the select. This function sort the array from the selected value you chose.

```
      const onChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value

    switch(value) {
        case "ascending":
            setDisplayPage(displayPage.sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label)))
            break
        case "descending":
            setDisplayPage(displayPage.sort((a, b) => b.label.localeCompare(a.label)))
            break
        case "high-price":
            setDisplayPage(displayPage.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price))
            break
        case "low-price":
             setDisplayPage(displayPage.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price))
            break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const objectData = [
  {name:'Javascript', price: 500},
  {name:'PHP', price: 3},
  {name:'Phyton', price: 399}
]


function App() {
  const [objectsToShow, setToShow] = React.useState(objectData)
  
  const compare = (a, b, ascendingOrder) => {
    if (a < b) {
      return ascendingOrder ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if (a > b) {
      return ascendingOrder ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  
  const handleChange = (value) => {
    if(value == 'none'){
        setToShow([...objectData])
    } else {
      let toType, toAscending
      switch(value){
        case 'ascending' : toType = true; toAscending = true; break;
        case 'descending' : toType = true; toAscending = false; break;
        case 'high' : toType = false; toAscending = true; break;
        case 'low' : toType = false; toAscending = false; break;
      }
      let current = [...objectData]
      current.sort((a, b) => toType ?
             compare(a.name, b.name, toAscending) 
             : 
             compare(a.price, b.price, toAscending))
      setToShow([...current])
    }
  }
  return(
    <div>
    <select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="none">Default</option>
      <option value="ascending">Alphabetically, A-Z</option>
      <option value="descending">Alphabetically, Z-A</option>
      <option value="high">Low to high</option>
      <option value="low">High to low</option>
    </select>
    {objectsToShow.map(elem => <p key={elem.name}>{elem.name} {elem.price}</p>)}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jacques! this is functioning properly !

Comment: ! What should I include in the code for the "Default" which return everything to the normal way without filtering? Sorry :)

Comment: @RicardoSánchez Done, answer edited =)

Comment: JeanJacques! You saved my life how can I rate your comment as the best one? bro you are a genious